# Delay in generation of dynamic controls in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, delay

I'm trying to generate a grid of **1x1 pixels** Images in .NET using VB.NET, using this code:

```
    For i = 1 To 500
        Dim img As New ImageButton
        img.ID = "ibtn" + i.ToString
        img.ImageUrl = "images/design/click.gif"
        form1.FindControl("upperpanel").Controls.Add(img)
    Next
```

**Problem is** that it takes a very long time to generate the HTML when I'm running this on page_load event. Can anyone help me out to speed up the rendering of the controls.  
**Also**, I want to add Click event on each image button. How can I do that ?? 

 Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to  create 500 consecutive 1x1 pixel images?

Comment: some kinda project work with overlapping panels/divisions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing to do is get the panel control once. Second, create your click method, and then add your handler.  This needs to be done prior to the page load event.  Use the page_Init event for creating your buttons when you need to add a handler.

```
    Private Sub WebForm1_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Dim tempPanel As Panel = form1.FindControl("upperpanel")

    If tempPanel Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    For i = 1 To 500
        Dim img As New ImageButton
        img.ID = "ibtn" + i.ToString
        img.ImageUrl = "images/design/click.gif"
        AddHandler img.Click, AddressOf ImageButton_Click
        tempPanel.Controls.Add(img)
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub ImageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim tempImageButton As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)

    Select Case tempImageButton.ID
        Case "ibtn1"
                    'blah
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

As far as performance goes, getting the panel control up front will improve performance.  Probably not much.  Creating 500 buttons is going to take some time.

Comment: @Robert Beaubien: Thanks a lot for the help..I sincerely request you to kindly provide an explanation for what is the reason you did this in the init instead of page_load (which I was doing). THanks..

And also, if you could help with this:
if I have resized my panel as 400x400, this would yield me 160,000 pixels or generated images...but they spread across the page instead of restraining themselves within the panel. How can I do this ??
Also, when I click on say 150000th pixel I get an HTML exception stating REQUEST TOO LONG...what could be the reason of this ??

Comment: Generating 160000 separate imagebuttons is  probably going to overflow  a lot.  I think you need to re-think your implementation.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but there is probably a better way.  As far as why you need to use the init event, you have to attach the handler earlier in the process.  If you don't, it won't work. Here is more information on the page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @RobertBeaubien I have to use a grid of transparent single pixel images for the purpose. :(
anyways Thanks a lot for your help.